# Cast Enum values from dropdown list

Tags: c#, enums

all,

There is a enum

```
public enum Response
{
good= 100,
bad= 101,
Somewhat good = 102,
......
}
```

this is bind to a drop-down with its text being displayed and value being set in value part of the list-item of the drop-down .

there is a base library method that is used to update the database

```
public bool UpdateResponse(int id , Enums.Response response)
{
//do business logic
}
```

On click of button I am getting the value of drop-down but can't cast it into enum for the method to accept.

```
button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var response = Enum.GetName(typeof(Enums.Response),DrpResponse.SelectedValue);
updateResponse(id , response) ;
//giving error of unnable to cast string to enum...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `response` variable is of type `string`, not `Response` as would be required. (Btw. this is a good example for why you should use the `var` keyword very carefully).

Change your code to this:

```
Enums.Response response = (Enums.Response)Enum.ToObject(typeof(Enums.Response),DrpResponse.SelectedValue);
updateResponse(id , response) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following code -

```
Response test; // set default value.
Enum.TryParse<Enums.Response> (DrpResponse.SelectedValue,out test);
```